# Decomposing inner product over complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I'm new to complex analysis and have a simple question.

I want to reduce an inner product $\left< A,B \right>$, where $A,B$ are complex matrices, to $c+id$ where $c,d$ are real numbers. How can I find a relation between $A,B$ and $c,d$? For example, $c$ itself can take the form of innter product of two real matrices. You can for the sake of argument assume $\left< A,B \right> = tr(A^HB)$.

Comment: How do you define this "inner product" $\langle A,B \rangle$ of two complex matrices?

Comment: You can for the sake of argument assume $\left< A,B \right> = tr(A^HB) \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Okay, "for the sake of argument".  But that defines a scalar complex value $c + id$.

Comment: Yes. I want to know the relation between $c,d$ and $A,B$. Something like, $c=\left< Re(A), Re(B) \right>$, where $Re(A)$ stands for the real part of the elements in the matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = A_r + iA_i, B = B_r + iB_i$ be the decompositions into real matrices. Then $$\begin{align}\langle A, B\rangle &= \langle A_r + iA_i, B_r + iB_i\rangle\\&=\left(\langle A_r, B_r\rangle + \langle A_i, B_i\rangle\right) + i\left(\langle A_r, B_i\rangle - \langle A_i, B_r\rangle\right)\end{align}$$

So $c = \langle A_r, B_r\rangle + \langle A_i, B_i\rangle$ and $d = \langle A_r, B_i\rangle - \langle A_i, B_r\rangle$, just as if $A, B$ were complex numbers and you were computing $A^*B$.

Comment: @hardmath - For some reason I thought his sample "inner product" was $\text{tr}(A^TB)$, so I went off of that. But apparently I misread it, as it is quite obviously $A^H$. I'll fix it. Thanks.